# Lazy loading of angular module

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router for routing in my angular app and want to lazy load the module.
Module is getting lazily loaded but i am not able to view the html content of it. Only blank screen is displayed.

In order to lazy load I just added this in my router file:

```
loadChildren:() => CustomerModule
```

Can someone help me with to resolve this.

Comment: can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: Does your lazily loaded module have a routing module?

Comment: Yes I have routing module